# For structs, do I have to call the constructor explicitly in C#?

Tags: c#, constructor, struct, explicit

The question is about the structs. When I declare a struct type variable/object (don't know which one suits better) or an array or list of structs, do I have to call the constructor explicitly like objects or just declaring will suffice like variables?

Comment: not sure if you are also asking if you need to new the container (e.g. List<T>), but the answer is yes.  :)

Answer (score 14):

**Structs in C# can be created with or without invoking a constructor.** In the case when no constructor is invoked, the members of the [struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ah19swz4%28VS.71%29.aspx) will be initialized to default values (essentially zeroed out), and the `struct` cannot be used until all of its fields are initialized.

From the documentation:

> When you create a struct object using
>   the new operator, it gets created and
>   the appropriate constructor is called.
>   Unlike classes, structs can be
>   instantiated without using the new
>   operator. If you do not use new, the
>   fields will remain unassigned and the
>   object cannot be used until all of the
>   fields are initialized.

Below are some examples:

```
struct Bar
{ 
   public int Val;  

   public Bar( int v ) { Val = v; }
}

public void Foo()
{
    Bar z;      // this is legal...
    z.Val = 5;

    Bar q = new Bar(5); // so is this...
    q.Val = 10;

    // using object initialization syntax...
    Bar w = new Bar { Val = 42; }
}
```

Arrays of structs are different than a single struct variable. When you declare an array of a struct type you are declaring a reference variable - as such, you must allocate it using the `new` operator:

```
Bar[] myBars = new Bar[10];  // member structs are initialized to defaults
```

You can also choose to use array initialization syntax if your struct has a constructor:

```
Bar[] moreBars = new Bar[] { new Bar(1), new Bar(2) };
```

You can get more sophisticated than this. If your `struct` has an implicit conversion operator from a primitive type, you can initialize it like so:

```
struct Bar
{ 
   public int Val;  

   public Bar( int v ) { Val = v; }

   public static implicit operator Bar( int v )
   {
       return new Bar( v );
   }
}

// array of structs initialized using user-defined implicit converions...
Bar[] evenMoreBars = new Bar[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that I've developed in C# for two years and never once used or even came across the implicit keyword!

Answer (score 0):

Struct is a `Value Type` in C#, so it uses Stack memory rather than Heap.

You can declare a struct variable in the regular way e.g `int a = 90;`,

int is a struct type in c#.

If you use `new` operator then the corresponding constructor will be invoked.